# is it possible check if given function is executing within other function or method?

Tags: php, function, php-5.3

```
function echo_parent_func() {
    echo // so what now ?
}

function somefunc() {
    echo_parent_func();
}

somefunc(); //should echo string 'somefunc'
```

Is that even possible with php ?

Comment: something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960805/php-determine-where-function-was-called-from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function get_caller_method() 
{ 
    $traces = debug_backtrace(); 

    if (isset($traces[2])) 
    { 
        return $traces[2]['function']; 
    } 

    return null; 
} 

function echo_parent_func() {
    echo get_caller_method();
}

function somefunc() {
    echo_parent_func();
}

somefunc(); //should echo string 'somefunc'
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php)

**EDIT** Just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5) too:

Comment: Call `debug_backtrace` with `false` as an argument (as for PHP 5.3), that will make it faster.