# Can the current method know from what method has been called?

Tags: php, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Caller function in PHP 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5)
>   [php: determine where function was called from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960805/php-determine-where-function-was-called-from)

Lets say

```
function item_description(){
    $var = 6;
    description($var);
}

function item_description_extended(){
    $var = 7;
    description($var);
}

function description(){
    if(called_from_item_description){
        echo 6;
    }else{
        echo 7;
    }
}
```

I know this functions make no sense... but my question here is if i can know what method called `descrption()`?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5

Comment: I believe no, but you can keep state in session, global var or something and write/read function's name from there, but it's kind of messy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php

`debug_backtrace` will tell who called you

Comment: Backtracing will tell you *too* much. While this works, unfortunately I believe the function name is prefixed with `debug_` for a reason. I've done this before, and after consideration, realized it was due to poor design choices, and the root of the problem was solved elsewhere.