# How to make a function behavior in different way if it called in a specific file?

Tags: php, function, autoload

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php: determine where function was called from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960805/php-determine-where-function-was-called-from)

I have an autoloading function `my_function($class)` that could be called by any script. It is called by PHP's `spl_autoload_call()` and that can happen everywhere. How do I script `my_function($class)` to detect when it is called by a specific `$file`?

Something like:

```
$file = '/htdocs/project/whatever.php';
if ($caller_file == $file) {
    ...
```

How do I find `$caller_file`?
I do understand this question is confusing but I can't put it in better words right now. So if you have any problem understanding just let me know in the comments.

**Edit (Context)** I want to make the script load a different class's file if the file the autoloader would load is the same in which the autoloader is called.

For example giving:

```
namespace Something;
class Random extends Random {}
```

should not load itself, but a different file in which we have:

```
namespace Something;
class Random { ... }
```

In other words:

What if I'm defining `MyName\Class` in `a/class.php` and I want to extends itself with `MyName\Class extends \MyName\Class` (inside `a/class.php`) but I want the autoloader to look `\MyName\Class` in `b/class.php` when it is asked within `a/class.php`?

Comment: @hakre, I tried to backtrace the script below, but `random.php` (Random file) never comes out in the backtrace when calling itself.

Comment: Where is your code in the question that makes use of backtrace? I don't see it.

Comment: I did a `var_dump()` in the autoloader script of `$debug` which comes out of `$debug = debug_backtrace()`. There's not the caller file I want because when he reach `a/random.php` the autoloader ask for `a/random.php` again (because of `Random extends Random`) causing the PHP "class not found" error. Instead I want the autoloader script to load `b/random.php` when `Random` is called within `a/random.php`. Do you get it?

Comment: The function(s) registered via `spl_autoload_register()` is/are never called if a class of the particular name is already defined within the specified namespace.

Comment: @Jeff: No I don't understand. The autoloader function get's a classname - not a file-name. So no idea why you talk about the autoloader reaches a file-name. And the code is still missing in your question, so it's absolutely not possible for me to decipher your problem.

Comment: @Lübnah, what if I'm defining `MyName\Class` in `a/class.php` and I want to extends itself with `MyName\Class extends \MyName\Class` inside `a/class.php` but I want the autoloader to look `\MyName\Class` in `b/class.php` when it is asked within `a/class.php`?

Comment: @hakre, Yeah, you use the autoloader to include a file which contains the class. You know? It's the purpose of the autoloader to load the class... anyway, my autoloader obliviously convert the class name into a path to a file. As far as you need to know the autoloader function is `function my_autoloader($class) { $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class); include(ROOT."a/$class.php"); }`.

Comment: @Jeff: I know what an autoloader is and use spl to manage those often. So what is your actual question? Your autoloader is actually pretty simple (and prone to attacks).

Comment: @hakre, please, read my last reply to Lubnah comment.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: Assuming they're referred to in the global namespace, `MyName\Class` and `\MyName\Class` are in the same namespace. See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Comment: @Lübnah, yep, that's the point.

Comment: @JeffPigarelli: Well then you're going to get a fatal, b/c you can't redefine a class that's already been defined, and you certainly can't make a class extend itself. Your autoload function won't even come into the picture in your cited example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried debug_backtrace() ?

Comment: Yes, but the file in which the class itself is called doesn't appear.