# Get source from where function was called from / get last function from backtrace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically the same question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960805/php-determine-where-function-was-called-from), but then a Ruby solution.

I have a class, with static functions that fill the class:

```
class Message
  attributes :message, :origin

  def initialize(params)
   self.origin = initialize_called_by
   super
  end

  def self.failed_to_save
    Message.new(message: 'Failed to save that thing!')
  end

  def self.failed_to_delete
    Message.new(message: 'Failed to delete that thing!')
  end
end
```

Where I'd expect `origin` to contain the following:

```
Message.failed_to_save.origin # failed_to_save
Message.failed_to_delete.origin # failed_to_delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
caller_locations(1,1)[0].label
```

If you extract this into a method, you might need to modify the first argument of caller_locations to look further up the stack trace.